# Invalid signatures and signed issue

Tags: apt, updates

If I perform sudo apt-get update. I obtain:

```
GPG error: http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 7638D0442B90D010 Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org> EXPKEYSIG CBF8D6FD518E17E1 Jessie Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org> 75DDC3C4A499F1A18CB5F3C8CBF8D6FD518E17E1
E: The repository 'http://http.debian.net/debian jessie Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks for the feedback.

My installed Ubuntu:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Comment: I'd remove that source from your system, as you won't get anything useful from it. Debian Jessie is EOL & has been for some time! - refer https://www.debian.org/News/2020/20200709

Comment: What is the best approach to perform this safely?

Comment: I'd suggest reversing how you added it... ie. if you used a text editor to add it to `/etc/apt/sources.list` then re-edit that file & remove it.  If you added it as a source in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` then remove that added file.  Given Debian *jessie* has been EOL since 30-June-2020 - you've likely only added it recently (~2.5 years living with that message makes me think it was recent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Removed the source from /etc/apt/sources.list